# Include php file in header tempate file

Tags: php, include

I have following files structure.

```
config.php
header.php
page.php
footer.php
```

The `header.php` includes the `config.php` file and and `page.php` includes `header.php`:

**header.php**

```
include ('config.php');
```

**page.php:**

```
include ('header.php');
include ('footer.php');
```

Now on this `page.php` if I want to access any function which is in `config.php`, it gives error as it cannot access the functions in `config.php` file.

It works if I include `config.php` file in the `page.php` also. However in this way I have to include that file in each of the page.

Is there anyway to include that file in the `header.php` file so that I don't have to include in each page?

**Edit:** 
**config.php** is very simple and has only connection string. Here is the content:

```
define('SOME_CONSTANT', 'xxx');

try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:Driver="..);        
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: can you show config.php

Comment: Based on what you have said, it should work the way you want, unless the function is namespaced.

Comment: By default you should be able to use functions from `config.php` in `page.php`, what version of PHP are you using? Also as a side note you should use `include_once` instead of `include` as you are going to run into problems later. Since you mentioned you have to include `config.php` in both `header.php` and `page.php` for it to work, you are including it twice. And sometimes this can cause problems.

Comment: @iCoders I edited the question, please see.

Comment: `config.php` you added, does not have any function.

Comment: @Starx it has only db connection string so that I don't have to make db connection in each file

Comment: Then why are you saying `Now on this page.php if I want to access any function which is in config.php, it gives error as it cannot access the functions in config.php file.` in your question, if you don't have any functions?

Comment: can you please show page.php

Comment: @Starx I apologize, function was not the right word, I perhaps wanted to say functionality. I just need to establish the database connection through that file.

Comment: Once you include the file the connection will establish, don't worry about that. Now if you want to access the variable `$db` from `config.php` you should use `global $db;` and that will use the global `$db` variable which is declared in `config.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions in config.php must be public

Ex.:
**config.php**

> public function func_name() {
>
> ```
>     // code
> ```
>
> }

Comment: That is assuming that config.php have a class.

Comment: config.php file has only db connection string. I edited the question.